# No se guarda la fecha y la hora actual al enviar el post

Tags: reactjs, hook

Me encuentro automatizando los post que realizo, para eso implementé un Hook useFormObj que contiene la lógica para validar y enviar forms. Todo funciona maravillosamente hasta que me dí cuenta que la fecha y la hora que se guarda es la del initialForm, muestro un ejemplo.

```
import moment from 'moment'
import { useForm } from '../hooks/useFormObj';

import React from "react";

let styles = {
  fontWeight: "bold",
  color: "#dc3545",
};

export default ({ user, config }) => {

  const validationsForm = (form) => {
    let errors = {};
    let regexSalary = /^.{6,8}$/;

    if (!form.salary.trim()) {
      errors.salary = "Solo numeros"
    } else if (!regexSalary.test(form.salary.trim())) {
      errors.salary = "Debe tener una longitud de 5 a 6 digitos"
    }

    return errors;
  }

  const current = new Date()
  const date = `${current.getFullYear() < 10 ? '0' + current.getFullYear() : current.getFullYear()}-${current.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (current.getMonth() + 1) : current.getMonth() + 1}-${current.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + current.getDate() : current.getDate()}`
  const hour = `${current.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + current.getHours() : current.getHours()}:${current.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + current.getMinutes() : current.getMinutes()}:${current.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + current.getSeconds() : current.getSeconds()}`


  let table = 'employees'

  const initialForm = {
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    salary: "",
    date_register: date + ' ' + hour
  }

  const {
    form,
    setForm,
    errors,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm(initialForm, validationsForm, table, config);

  const setDate = async () => {
    let newForm = {
      ['date_register']: date + ' ' + hour
    }

    //concatenacion del form actal con la newForm ES7
    let result = {
      ...form,
      ...newForm
    }

    return result
  };

  const submit = () => {
    handleSubmit(
      e,
      'create',
      () => { }, //actionPost vacio
      () => { setDate } //actionPrev para que envíe la fecha y la hora actual
    )
  }

  return (

    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <div className='col-md-4'>
        <label>first_name</label>
        <input
          className='form-control '
          type="text"
          name="first_name"
          placeholder="write first_name"
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onKeyUp={handleBlur}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={form.first_name}
          required
        />
        {errors.first_name && <p style={styles}>{errors.first_name}</p>}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className='btn btn-success' >
        Guardar
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Bueno el form es cencillo, les dejo un ejemplo del form, y un Hook personalizado de donde destructuro el form entre otras cosas. Al guardar los datos, me guarda la fecha y la hora a la cual se cargó el formulario y no cuando presioné el botón. Intenté algo así, sin embargo el mismo resultado. **(Omitir esta parte)**

```
       <button type="submit" className='btn btn-success' onClick={setForm({
          ...form,
          ['date_register']: moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"),
        })}>
          Guardar
        </button>
```

La funcion handleSubmit  que destructuré del Hook personalizado es la siguiente.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

export const useForm = (initialForm, validateForm, table, config) => {
  const [table, setTable] = useState(table)
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e, funcion) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setForm({
      ...form,
      [name]: value,
    });
    if (funcion) { funcion() }
  };

  const handleBlur = (e, funcion) => {
    handleChange(e, () => { });
    setErrors(validateForm(form));
    if (funcion) { funcion() }
  };

  // e button
  // actionServer: create - update
  // actionPost: funcion execute after send post
  // actionPrev: function execute before send post
  const handleSubmit = async (
    e,
    actionServer,
    actionPost,
    actionPrev
  ) => {

    let errResult = await validateForm(form)

    if (Object.keys(errResult).length === 0) {
      try {

        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Cargando!',
          html: 'Espere mientras se cargan los datos...',
          timerProgressBar: false,
          didOpen: () => {
            Swal.showLoading()
          },
        })

        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.reset()

        var res = ''

        if (actionPrev) {
          let newForm = await actionPrev() //trae el newForm para realizar el post

          res = await sendPost(actionServer, newForm)
        } else {
          res = await sendPost(actionServer, form)
        }

        Swal.close()
        const { err, msg } = res.data;
        if (err) {
          Swal.fire(err)
          return;
        } else {
          Swal.fire(msg)
          setForm(initialForm)
          if (actionPost) { actionPost() }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Ocurrió un error al realizar el post ' + actionServer + ' ' + table + ' Err: ' + err);
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  const sendPost = async (actionServer, newform) => {
    return axios.post(`${config.urlServer}/server/${actionServer}/${table}`, newform)
  }

  return {
    form,
    setForm,
    errors,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
  };
};
```

Comment: Bueno supongo que dejaste vacía la propiedad `date_registered` en `initalForm` cuando intentaste `['date_register']: moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: NO exactamente, porque me registra con la fecha y la hora en la cual cargué el componente. Muestro un ejemplo: setForm({
          ...form,
          ['date_register']: date + ' ' + hour,
        })

Comment: también intenté realizar un actionPrev en el handleSumbit. Dejo el código en el Hook . No me funciona y le implementé un async await

Comment: Y claro las llamar al método se lo envio. También lo dejo en onSubmit.

Comment: También dejo todo el hook personalizado del post

Comment: Saben que observé mostrando la fecha y la hora actual, que se actualizada cada vez que realizo un onChange... Claro se puede dejar así pero la fecha que se guarda debe ser cuando yo presione el boton de guardar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con base a lo anteriormente planteado, después de ejecutar varios proyectos y revisar documentación me dí cuenta que debo obtener un nuevo objeto con las modificaciones que quiero  y retornarlo para que ese nuevo objeto modificado previamente sea enviado en el post.
Dejo el código completamente funcional. Espero que sirva y sea de utilidad para muchos.
Muchas gracias a todos los que participaron en el foro.